# Inserting Parent Child XML Data into SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a xml document as string. I need to insert the data into Master and Detail tables in SQL Server 2008.

I tried OpenXML and I want to use some other way in VB.net. I am using .net 3.5

```
<Orders>
    <Product>
      <productID>1</productID>
      <productName>Pens</productName>
      <ProductDetails>     
         <productID>1</productID>
         <cost>100</cost> 
      </ProductDetails>
     </Product>

     <Product>
      <productID>2</productID>
      <productName>Books</productName>
      <ProductDetails>     
         <productID>2</productID>
         <cost>1000</cost> 
      </ProductDetails>
     </Product>
</Orders>
```

Comment: And what do you want to store where, from this XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "[Designing and Implementing Semistructured Storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522446.aspx)", and next time, start your search for basic SQL Server information at [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx).